# z-index of absolute element inside a relative element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position two divs on left and right ends of parent div with some negative margin. See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/239/

But my absolute divs (part with negative margins) are stacked behind paren div. Instead I want them on top of parent div.

What is wrong with my code below?

Even though I set z-index:100 for absolute elements.

HTML

```
<div class="item1">
  <div class="item3 prev ">
      Item3
  </div>
  <div class="item4 next">
      Item4
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
      item2
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
      item2
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item1 {
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:2px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.item2 {
 position:relative;
  float:left;
  background-color: green;
  width : 255px;
  height : 205px;
  margin-right:6px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.item3, .item4 {
  top:65px;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  z-index:100;
}

.prev {
    left:-25px;
}
.next {
    right:-25px;
}
```

Comment: They look on top to me - http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/z9Unk/240/

Comment: For me too. Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Which browser do you use :-) ?

Comment: what I meant was in case of text "item4", "m4" is not visible and in case of text "item3", "ite" is not visible.. I understand for left side its the end of body...BUT for right side m4 sld be visible

Answer (score 1):

Your problem **was not** that the absolutely placed elements get placed below the parent div, but rather - that you pushed them outside the bounds of the parent div because of the negative margins.

**Solution:**

Being that you stated that you need negative margins as per the spec - modify your negative margins and change their `text-align` property.

```
.prev {
    left:-15px;
    text-align: right;
}
.next {
    right:-15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/z9Unk/242/)**

Comment: I want -ve margin so that item3,4 goes little bit out of parent div....thats the design I want to have

Comment: So change the margin according to your needs & in a way that the text doesn't get cut

Comment: thanks for your response for helping me out...I could find the "way" to set margins so text does not get cut...hence I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the container div is `overflow: hidden`.
This css property is cutting prev/next divs.

See my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/LLhZx/